# Dealing with large Array data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using javascript NDollar library for gesture recognition with Ruby on Rails. I need to process more than 1000 gesture data in single run and store in an array where each gesture looks like in the following format:

```
Multistroke {Name: "gesture_name", NumStrokes: 2, Unistrokes: Array(8)}
Name:"gesture_name"
NumStrokes:2
Unistrokes:Array(8)
0:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
1:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
2:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
3:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
4:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
5:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
6:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
7:Unistroke {Name: "gesture_name", Points: Array(48), StartUnitVector: Point, Vector: Array(96)}
length:8
__proto__:Array(0)
__proto__:Object
```

As the size of array increases, RAM gets overloaded and browser freezes. How can I overcome this problem? 
Here is the link for [NDollar](http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/dollar/ndollar.html)

Comment: Without seeing your code there's not really much we can help with regard to performance optimisation. Weight of data is the main issue though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can see what i am doing in this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndollar-js, (for web browser) I am passing around 1000 such triangle like gestures